# Check In-app purchase auto renewal subscription in sandbox mode

Tags: ios, objective-c, subscription, auto-renewable

I'm having a delay in receipt updating for the auto renewal in my app.

As a example if user subscribed for 7 day subscription with one week free trial,

- means 1 week =  3 mins
- auto renewal will happen 5 times.
- Total time = 15 mins.

So according to above the info, the within the first 15 mins I should have a active subscription. But sometimes it doesn't returns a active subscription.

The issue I found is even after the first 3 mins, the receipt has not renewed, So there for when I compare the expire date with the current time it returns as subscription period expires.

Is this something common in sandbox mode or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Sometimes the sandbox will simulate the user cancelling renewal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some how i was able to solve the issue. Initially in my device i have not set my time set automatically. Some how the time which i have set is 5 mins more than the real time. So when validating the the expire date it always shows as a expired subscription.

Since the time period really small(3 mins) for a week, when testing in sandbox mode. It gave me the wrong information, i guess.

Hope this will be helpful.Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

```
Testing Auto-Renewable Subscriptions

When testing auto-renewable subscriptions in the test environment, keep in mind that the duration times are compressed. Additionally, test subscriptions only auto-renew a maximum of six times. Table 3-1 lists the compressed duration times.

Table 3-1  Subscription durations for testing
Actual duration
Test duration
1 week    3 minutes
1 month   5 minutes
2 months 10 minutes
3 months 15 minutes
6 months 30 minutes
1 year    1 hour
```

Refer this url:
https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/dev7e89e149d